# jenkins wouldn't execute python script correctly

Tags: python, windows-7, jenkins

I  set up a job that want to execute an action that open the local browser. I write it use the python script:

```
import webbrowser
if __name__=="__main__":
     webbrowser.open("http://www.example.com")
```

Then,i click Build now button on jenkins dashboard, it can execute successful and show successful as a result at last. But nothing happen for browser.It's very wierd that other python script could execute correctly, I have no idea why?

Addition:This jenkins(Jenkins ver. 1.524) is installed on my laptop and my laptop's OS is Win7, i start jenkins as a Windows Service. Do u have any idea?

Comment: Could you please post more about your job configuration?

Comment: This is a simple job that only one purpose, i only want to open a browser with assigned url(this url is a server that the browser will run some js test case). so it only consists of the python script code part. Does it enough for u?

Comment: i feel this issue like a sub task for the job, i don't know whether the jenkins support this type case

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Jenkins as a Windows service, by default it runs as user Local System. Did you check the box titled "Allow service to interact with desktop"?. If that does not help you may have to set the service to log on as an actual user, instead of Local System. This is a common problem with running any process with a GUI from Jenkins.